# How to combine my pagination script and filter script?

Tags: javascript

I have a pagination script which is working, as well my filter script. Unfortunately once I filter, it filters all the search item and it exceeds the maximum limit of my pagination which should be the case.

I need my pagination and filter script work together. I have sample table for you to use.

There is my entire script:

```
    document.getElementById("myInput").onkeyup = function() {
        filterBar()
    };

    function filterBar() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.disp    lay = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    };
    paginateTable();
    function paginateTable() {
        var currentPage = 0;
        var numPerPage = 10;
        var table = $('#myTable');

        table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage,
                (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
        var numRows = table.find('tbody tr').length;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);

        table.bind('repaginate', function() {
            table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage,
                    (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
            $('#totalEntries').text(numRows);

            if (numRows == 0) {
                $('#minEntry').text(numRows);
            } else {
                $('#minEntry').text((currentPage * 10) + 1);
            }

            if (currentPage == 0 || numRows == 0) {
                $('.previousPage').hide();
            } else {
                $('.previousPage').show();
                $('.previousPage').data('page', currentPage - 1);
            }

            if (currentPage == (numPages - 1) || numRows == 0) {
                $('.nextPage').hide();
                $('#maxEntry').text(numRows);
            } else {
                $('.nextPage').show();
                $('.nextPage').data('page', currentPage + 1);
                if (numRows < 10) {
                    $('#maxEntry').text(numRows);
                } else {
                    $('#maxEntry').text((currentPage * 10) + 10);
                }
            }

            $('#currentPage').text(currentPage + 1);
        });

        table.trigger('repaginate');

        $('.previousPage, .nextPage').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            currentPage = $(this).data('page');
            table.trigger('repaginate');
        });
    }
```

This is my sample table with button for pagination

Filter:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 60%;">English</th>
            <th style="width: 40%;">Other Language</th>
            <th style="width: 30%;">Status</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="table-pagination">
    <div class="page-control">
        Showing <span id="minEntry">0</span> to <span id="maxEntry">0</span>
        of <span id="totalEntries">0</span> entries
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#" class="previousPage">Newer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="previousPage">&lt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="currentPage" class="page-number">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nextPage">&gt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nextPage">Older</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it exceeds the maximum limit of my pagination"? Do you mean that if you want to render 10 items per page, your AJAX filter has the capacity to write more than 10 search results?

Comment: when I search something in the table like "a" it will show all datas that has "a" in the table. I should only show 10, then the others will be on the other page as pagination.